# Can i monitor a variable changed in another class in kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Im in a fragment1 and i want go to fragment2 if an event occurred in a class called from the fragment1. I have tried a callback of fuction: function in Class call a function in fragment1 to go in fragment but i collect this error:

```
Process: com.example.ilmiogioco, PID: 7992java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method addObserver must be called on the main thread
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.enforceMainThreadIfNeeded(LifecycleRegistry.java:317)
at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:172)
at androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistryController.performRestore(SavedStateRegistryController.java:61)
at androidx.navigation.NavBackStackEntry.<init>(NavBackStackEntry.java:88)
at androidx.navigation.NavBackStackEntry.<init>(NavBackStackEntry.java:73)
at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:1138)
at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:944)
at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:877)
at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:863)
at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:851)
at com.example.ilmiogioco.FullscreenFragmentSolo.follow(FullscreenFragmentSolo.kt:77)
at com.example.ilmiogioco.Solo.SpaceView.update(SpaceView.kt:276)
at com.example.ilmiogioco.Solo.SpaceView.run(SpaceView.kt:120)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

EDIT: I have fullscreenfragmentsolo (fragment1) that want in gameoverfragment (fragment2) if the class spaceview called in fullscreenfragmentsolo collect a lost game. The function follow() is called by spaceview for return in fullscreenfragmentsolo (maybe this is the thread error).

```
 class FullscreenFragmentSolo : Fragment() {

private var spaceView: SpaceView? = null
private lateinit var backgroundMusic: MediaPlayer
private lateinit var window: Window
private var binding: FragmentFullscreenSoloBinding? = null
object size{
    var x = 0
    var y = 0
}


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    (activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!.supportActionBar!!.hide()
    getActivity()?.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    val soundEffects = SoundEffects(requireContext())

    soundEffects.playSound(SoundEffects.backgroundMusic)

    val outMetrics = DisplayMetrics()

    getActivity()?.getWindow()?.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
    window = activity?.getWindow()!!
    window.attributes.width
    window.attributes.height

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        val display = activity?.display
        display?.getRealMetrics(outMetrics)
    } else {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        val display = activity?.windowManager?.defaultDisplay
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        display?.getMetrics(outMetrics)
    }

    size.y = outMetrics.heightPixels
    size.x = outMetrics.widthPixels

    backgroundMusic = MediaPlayer.create(requireContext(), R.raw.background_music)
    backgroundMusic.isLooping = true
    backgroundMusic.start()
    val fragmentBinding = FragmentFullscreenSoloBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    binding = fragmentBinding
    fragmentBinding.root
    spaceView = SpaceView(requireContext(), size, this)

    return spaceView
}
fun follow(){

    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_fullscreenFragmentSolo_to_gameoverFragment)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding?.soloFragment = this
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    spaceView?.resume()
}
fun stopFunction() {
    spaceView?.stop()
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()

    backgroundMusic.release()
    spaceView?.pause()

}
override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    binding = null
}
```

GameoverFragment:

```
open class GameoverFragment : Fragment() {
private var binding: GameoverFragmentBinding? = null


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val fragmentBinding = GameoverFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    binding = fragmentBinding
    return fragmentBinding.root
    return view
}
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding?.gameoverFragment = this
}
fun Menu(){
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_gameoverFragment_to_startFragment)
}

> override fun onDestroyView() {
>     super.onDestroyView()
>     binding = null }
```

Can you help me?

Comment: This exception is due to your code calling (through navigation and through `SavedStateRegistryController.performRestore`) the `LifecycleRegistry.addObserver` from a thread other than the Main thread. Share the relevant code and maybe we can spot the problem. You have to ensure that you call the navigation from the main thread.

Comment: @Ma3x Added! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception is due to your code calling (through navigation) the `LifecycleRegistry.addObserver` from a thread other than the Main thread. You have to ensure that you call the navigation from the main thread.

Change to this in the `follow()` function

```
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper

// ...

fun follow() {
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_fullscreenFragmentSolo_to_gameoverFragment)
    }
}
```